# How is this website controlling the user's navigation between tabs, without any permissions?

Tags: javascript, outlook, tabs

When on the [Outlook web app](https://outlook.live.com/mail/inbox), clicking the "Calendar" link opens in a new tab. So far so normal.

[image: calendar link]

The interesting part happens when clicking the "Mail" tab on this new tab; it somehow redirects focus to the original tab! The two tabs are now "tied", and clicking mail / calendar in each tab brings the other tab to focus.

I'm assuming this is done via some JavaScript wizardry. Interestingly, reopening one of the tabs loses this "tied" status, so I'm assuming it's related to how the new tab is opened. I did try and research how tabs could be controller by a website, but all results implied it was impossible.

It's hard to explain the behaviour fully without a video / gif, but my question is essentially:

**How can a website control navigation between tabs in the browser?**

I'm using Chrome x64 71.0.3578.98.

Comment: I think it can be done via cookies, the local storage or even some remote connection with websockets or HTTP requests but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) returns a reference to the opened [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), wich in return recieves a backreference to the [opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a window opens another window, you can switch focus back and forth between them using:

```
// Open new window from current window
let yourTabName = window.open("google.com");

// Focus parent window, from new window
window.opener.focus();

// Focus new window, from parent window
yourTabName.focus();
```

Here's an example fiddle (make sure you allow popups): https://jsfiddle.net/pg74mxvd/

If you run the fiddle, you'll see it opens a new tab. You can then go back to the fiddle tab and click the HTML button and the focus should go to the just opened tab.

I suspect this is what they are doing, since when you click the "Calendar" button you are essentially opening a new window from an existing one, which would then allow you to invoke the above methods.

Comment: This definitely seems close, but how could this new tab set the focus back to the original tab?

Comment: As long as the new tab was opened from the original tab, you can switch focus back to the original tab using `window.opener.focus()`. `window.opener` refers to the opening window.

Comment: Got it, that seems like the solution then. Will mark as answer when I can, thanks.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. I'm sure you already know, but just in case -- you can read more about these methods [on the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I was having trouble working out what to Google to answer the question, I'll look here too next time. I'm not particularly a web dev (Android, like you), was just curious. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of methods for doing this, based on the fact that all the tabs are part of the same domain (outlook.com) so the browser will allow some sorts of communication between them. Here's a simple mechanism using polling of `window.localStorage`:

```
 onUserClickCalendar(() => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('focus', 'calendar');
 });

 function checkForTabFocusUpdate() {
      const focus = windows.localStorage.getItem('focus');
      if (focus !== currentFocus) {
         switchTabFocus(focus);
      }
 }

 setInterval(checkForTabFocusUpdate, 100);
```

Comment: What is `switchTabFocus`, sorry? This does seem to explain how data can be transferred between the tabs, but I'm not understanding the focus switching yet.